# Plot top frequencies with with ggdotplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

My data consists of a list of colleges, 2-year or 4-year, and number enrolled. Below is a sample of what it looks like but I have over 3600 colleges and universities in the full dataset.

```
institute <- tibble(
  inst          = c("Southwestern College", "San Diego State University", 
                   "Grossmont College", "San Diego Mesa College", "San Diego City College",
                   "University of California-San Diego", "California State University-San Marcos",
                   "Cuyamaca College", "San Diego Miramar College", "University of California-Berkeley",
                   "Univerity of California-Los Angeles", "University of California-Santa Barbara",
                   "University of California-Santa Curz",
                   "California Polytechnic State University", "Palomar College",
                   "California State University-Fullerton", "University of California-Irvine",
                   "University of California-Davis", "University of California-Riverside",
                   "Arizona State University", "San Francisco State University",
                   "California State University-Chico", "Grand Canyon University",
                   "University of San Diego", "Northern Arizona University"),
  year         = c('2-year', "4-year", '2-year', '2-year', '2-year', "4-year", "4-year",
                   '2-year', '2-year', "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "2-year",
                   "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", "4-year", 
                   "4-year", "4-year", "4-year"),
  num_enrolled = c(2124, 1531, 1299, 1158, 783, 780, 729, 694, 513, 245, 243, 215, 
                   196, 189, 156, 154, 153, 139, 132, 96, 94, 91, 86, 79, 78)
)
```

and I've plotted the data...

```
ggdotchart(institute, x = "inst", y = "num_enrolled",
           sorting = "descending",  # Sort value in descending order
           rotate = TRUE,                                # Rotate vertically
           dot.size = 2.5,                                 # Large dot size
           color = "year",
           y.text.col = FALSE) +
  labs(title = "Top 25 institutions where students enrolled in 2020",
       subtitle = "San Diego students split equally between two and four-year institutions",
       x = element_blank(), y = "Students Enrolled") +
  theme_minimal()
```

The objective is to only show the top 5 college and universities. **Can this be done after ggdotchart sorts the data?**

Comment: Why not just feed `institute %>% arrange(desc(num_enrolled)) %>% slice_head(n=5)` instead of `institute` to ggdotchart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just feed `institute %>% arrange(desc(num_enrolled)) %>% slice_head(n=5)` instead of `institute` to ggdotchart?

```r
ggdotchart(
  institute %>% arrange(desc(num_enrolled)) %>% head(5),
  x = "inst", 
  y = "num_enrolled",
  sorting = "descending",  # Sort value in descending order
  rotate = TRUE,                                # Rotate vertically
  dot.size = 2.5,                                 # Large dot size
  color = "year",
  y.text.col = FALSE
  ) +
  labs(title = "Top 25 institutions where students enrolled in 2020",
       subtitle = "San Diego students split equally between two and four-year institutions",
       x = element_blank(),
       y = "Students Enrolled") +
  theme_minimal()
```